# How to get Check Out time for employee who is working on night shift

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table to store attendances of employees, check in and check out respectively. Most people work in day shift while most work overnight. For those who are working in day time it's calculating and showing data fine, but those who are working overnight I am able to get the exact attendance for them.
Here is the structure and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Shifts
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ShiftName VARCHAR(25),
StartTime TIME,
EndTime TIME,
IsNightShift bit
)

INSERT INTO Shifts VALUES (1, 'Day Shift', '09:00:00', '18:00', 0);
INSERT INTO Shifts VALUES (2, 'Night Shift', '21:00:00', '05:00', 1);


CREATE TABLE Attendance
(
ID INT,
EmpCode INT,
ShiftCode INT, 
CheckIn DATETIME,
CheckOut DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (ShiftCode)
REFERENCES Shifts(ID)
)



INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (1, 12, 1, '2019-09-01 09:16:23', NULL)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (2, 12, 1, NULL, '2019-09-01 18:01:56')
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (3, 07, 2, '2019-09-01 21:00:00', NULL)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (4, 07, 2, NULL, '2019-09-02 08:48:21')
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (5, 12, 1, '2019-09-02 09:27:00', NULL)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (6, 12, 1, NULL, '2019-09-02 18:45:00')
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (7, 07, 2, '2019-09-02 21:19:17', NULL)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (8, 07, 2, NULL, '2019-09-02 23:30:56')
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (9, 07, 2, '2019-09-03 00:23:00', NULL)
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (10, 07, 2, NULL, '2019-09-03 07:19:00')
```

I want to get how many times in a day employee have checked in or checked out as well so for employee `07` when I am going to get the attendance for `'2019-09-02'` it's should show following result set. It means employee first checked in at 09:19 PM on `2019-09-02` then left for some time at 11:30 PM and then came back again on `12:23 AM` and then left in the morning at `07:19 AM`.
As his shift timing are from `09:00 PM` till `05:00 AM` so he can work overnight and the attendnace will be counted for `2019-09-02`

```
EmpCode   CheckIn               
07        2019-09-02 21:19:17
07        2019-09-03 00:23:00

EmpCode   CheckOut               
07        2019-09-02 23:30:56
07        2019-09-03 07:19:00
```

I am using these queries to get the result set.

```
DECLARE @givenDate DATE = '2019-09-02';
DECLARE @EmpCode INT = 07;
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CheckIn) AS RowNum, EmpCode, CheckIn
FROM Attendance, Shifts
WHERE Attendance.ShiftCode = Shifts.ID AND
CAST(CheckIn AS DATE) = CAST(@givenDate AS DATE) AND EmpCode=@EmpCode
AND CheckIn IS NOT NULL;

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CheckOut) As RowNum, EmpCode, CheckOut
FROM Attendance, Shifts
WHERE Attendance.ShiftCode = Shifts.ID AND
CAST(CheckOut AS DATE) = 
CASE WHEN IsNightShift = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(@givenDate AS DATE)) ELSE CAST(@givenDate AS DATE) END
AND EmpCode=@EmpCode
```

Note that I am not using the Shift timings in my query maybe someone can help me out how I can make it handy and that might help me get the desired result set.

Comment: how do you get EmpCode 07 check in twice at `21:19` and `23:30` ? Isn't it `23:30` suppose to be a check out ?

Comment: @Squirrel wait yeah my bad. Let me edit this.

Comment: what is the expected result like ?

Comment: @Squirrel The expected result is given above the one I updated. There are basically 2 queries 1 to get the Check Ins and other to get Check Outs.
That result is actually what I require

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my answer from the OP's [(deleted) duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58198862/3484879) here anyway:

```
DECLARE @date date = '20190902';

WITH CheckInOut AS(
    SELECT A.ID,
           A.EmpCode,
           A.ShiftCode,
           A.CheckIn,
           LEAD(A.CheckOut) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpCode ORDER BY COALESCE(A.CheckIn,A.CheckOut)) AS CheckOut
    FROM dbo.Attendance A)
SELECT S.ShiftName,
       ST.ShiftStart,
       ST.ShiftEnd,
       CIO.CheckIn,
       CIO.CheckOut
FROM dbo.Shifts S
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:00:00',S.StartTime), CONVERT(datetime2(0),@date)),
                         DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN S.EndTime < S.StartTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:00:00',S.EndTime), CONVERT(datetime2(0),@date))))) ST(ShiftStart,ShiftEnd)
     JOIN CheckInOut CIO ON CIO.CheckIn >= ST.ShiftStart 
                        AND CIO.CheckIn < ST.ShiftEnd;
```

Comment: Why is query not working when both Check In and Check Out are in same row ?
Just like this.
`INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (11, 07, 2, '2019-09-18 21:07:00.000', '2019-09-19 08:51:23.000')`

Comment: It's showing NULL in ChecOut if I insert record in this format in table.

Comment: Because in your sample, they were on different rows, Doonie. Why would I expect a value for `CheckIn` and `CheckOut` to both have non-`NULL` values when **none** of your sample data has that... If you look at your sample data (and test) the scenario you describe does not exist: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8503ddb00d20c9bd837fb1b4a1035b0e)

Comment: Why is the answer limited to what is provided ? Obviously no one can imagine the scenarios initially, it comes with the passage if time. Your query shouldn't be restricted to some specific answer.

Comment: I din't mean that, appreciate your answer and help and it helped me a lot as well.I guess I just am not able to get the desired result from days and that's making me sound rude. Again I'm sorry for sounding ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, your shift table ends the night shift at 5:00 and the last checkout for Emp 07 is after 7:00 am.  But give it a go:

```
DECLARE @nEmpID INT = 7
DECLARE @givenDate DATE = '2019-09-02';

;WITH CTE as (
    SELECT  DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,'00:00:00',StartTime),CAST(@givenDate as datetime)) ShiftStart
            ,DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,'00:00:00',EndTime),DATEADD(day, CASE WHEN IsNightShift = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,CAST(@givenDate as datetime))) ShiftEnd
            ,ID
            , ShiftName
FROM #Shifts
)

select EmpCode,ShiftName,CheckIn,CheckOut 
from #Attendance t1
INNER JOIN CTE t2 on t1.ShiftCode = t2.ID
WHERE t1.EmpCode = @nEmpID and 
        ((t1.CheckIn >= t2.ShiftStart and t1.CheckIN <= t2.ShiftEnd)
            OR (t1.CheckOut >= t2.ShiftStart and t1.CheckOut <= t2.ShiftEnd))
```

**EDIT: If you needed to account for overtime then this edit will handle that as well:**

```
DECLARE @nEmpID INT = 7
DECLARE @givenDate DATE = '2019-09-02';

;WITH CTE as (
    SELECT  DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,'00:00:00',StartTime),CAST(@givenDate as datetime)) ShiftStart
            ,DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,'00:00:00',EndTime),DATEADD(day, CASE WHEN IsNightShift = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,CAST(@givenDate as datetime))) ShiftEnd
            , DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,'00:00:00',StartTime),CAST(DATEADD(day,1,@givenDate) as datetime)) NextShiftStart
            ,ID
            , ShiftName
FROM #Shifts
)

select EmpCode,ShiftName,CheckIn,CheckOut 
from #Attendance t1
INNER JOIN CTE t2 on t1.ShiftCode = t2.ID
WHERE t1.EmpCode = @nEmpID and 
        ((t1.CheckIn >= t2.ShiftStart and t1.CheckIN <= t2.ShiftEnd)
            OR (t1.CheckOut >= t2.ShiftStart and t1.CheckOut <= t2.NextShiftStart))
```